# Finding Interval of Convergence (Series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find the interval of convergence for a power series and I have determined that it is on -1, 1. Now I need to determine the convergence of the endpoints. The answer key states that interval is [-1, 1). However, I am not sure if this is correct?

original series

$\sum\frac {(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}$

at x = -1

$\sum\frac {(-1)^n(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$

at x = 1

$\sum\frac {(-1)^n(1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$

From my calculations, I got (-1, 1]. Meaning x at -1 diverges and x at 1 converges.

I can show how got these answers, but I would like to know first which is correct.

Comment: You're right, this diverges at $-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP calculations are correct, interval of convergence is (-1, 1]